# Invisible Staircase

Tags: riddle

I offer breathing without breath
and dancing up and down, round and round
in (mostly) perfect time
and, I promise,
I'll never miss a step.

Though diving, flying or driving
it's all upon my stairs
from Kitty Hawk to Clermont
moving from wherever, to wherever
with whoever, doing whatever
but if you want the truth
nothing here has been anywhere
(except perhaps, round the bend)

There's no two ways about it
my brother's never told a lie.
But I'll deceive you any way I can,
and if you stumble upon these steps
you won't find me
I never stop, I never rest
and though it may appear that I have left
nothing on these steps
has ever felt the need to die.

What am I?

```
First Hint
```

> Here's half a way to solve 
>  a clue, in fact, it's key 
>  and a door is like a lens 
>  altogether but unseen; 
>  however long your eyes persist 
>  I can certainly tell you this, 
>  you'll never walk through 
>  my locked doors 
>  (after all, what is a door 
>  when a door does not exist)

```
Second Hint
```

> To and from, and Inbetweens 
>  cascade across my steps 
>  and though there are no doors 
>  no walls, no metal bars 
>  there are cels to always 
>  keep things kempt

Comment: Is it DNA? A double helix?

Comment: I have a thought that its the moon [with the hints of movement/orbit], with an off reference to "One small step for man one giant leap for mankind"... However I am struggling to fill the gaps. (Maybe about the moon landing/conspiracy?)

Comment: I like your ideas guys! Unfortunately it's not what I had in mind, so I'll post a hint later today!

Comment: I'm wondering if there is something involving lines of latitude, as KittyHawk and Claremont are only a few degrees apart vertically. Interestingly, the route between the two cities is very straightforward.

Comment: @tfitzger I changed that line to make it easier - I feel like it may have been too broad a clue before! :)

Comment: Is it something to do with quantum physics? I feel that the steps are the orbits in the atom.

Comment: @valuable_asset it is not! I put up another hint which should shed some light on the riddle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some more pieces to fill in, but are you

> Hand Drawn Animation

I offer breathing without breath

> It's possible to animate a character breathing without actually breathing

and dancing up and down, round and round
in (mostly) perfect time
and, I promise,
I'll never miss a step.

> Animated dancers will always hit their cues

Though diving, flying or driving
it's all upon my stairs

> In this form of animation, all movement is done by moving cels in 'steps'

from Kitty Hawk to Clermont
moving from wherever, to wherever
with whoever, doing whatever

> It's possible for animated characters to do pretty much anything

but if you want the truth
nothing here has been anywhere
(except perhaps, round the bend)

> While animation can represent any place, it physically doesn't really move

There's no two ways about it
my brother's never told a lie.

> This could be in reference to other forms of media. Cameras show us the real world (even though we can mock things up)

But I'll deceive you any way I can,

> but animation can defy all reality

and if you stumble upon these steps
you won't find me

> if you mess up the steps of cels, you are likely to mess up the entire animation

I never stop, I never rest
and though it may appear that I have left
nothing on these steps
has ever felt the need to die.

> Hand drawn animation has fallen out of vogue recently because of the advent of CG. However, the images on the cels, now forever recorded to film and later digital media, will never truly disappear from the world.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: here are some things that should help you :  [however long your eyes persist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) //
[it's key/what's a door when a door does not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Pi or 22/7 (the division symbol indicating the step)

but i am not sure, and only these lines make sense

and dancing up and down, round and round 
in (mostly) perfect time
and, I promise, 
I'll never miss a step.

> Different numbers in Pi

Though diving, flying or driving
it's all upon my stairs

> pi contains sequences which can describe any thing

I never stop, I never rest,

Comment: Interesting thought, but not what I had in mind! I'll post a new hint later today!

Comment: @valuable-asset new hint is up!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a dream?  like an invisible staircase, a dream carries us, invisibly, to a different place

nothing here has been anywhere

> we may dream of many places, but we are not actually there

breathing without breath

> a dream is not real, but seems like real life while we experience it

diving, flying or driving -- moving from wherever, to wherever
with whoever, doing whatever

> movement in a dream is completely unrestrained; we can go anywhere by any means

my brother's never told a lie

> sleep and death are often depicted as brothers; while dreams can seem like real life, death is unambiguous

I'll deceive you any way I can

> dreams can be confusing and enigmatic; people and things in dreams morph and change places

nothing on these steps has ever felt the need to die.

> we often dream of our own death, which (happily) has not actually happened

altogether but unseen however long your eyes persist

> we "see" many things, vividly, in dreams, but we are not actually seeing through our eyes

Comment: You are by far the closest - buuuut not quite! Your logic is going mostly the right way and it looks like you picked up on a lot of the clues that others had missed, you just took it to a different, not-as-complete conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The heart

in (mostly) perfect time
and, I promise,
I'll never miss a step.

I never stop, I never rest

> Referencing the heart always beating in time (mostly)

But I'll deceive you any way I can,

> reference to the bible verse saying the heart is deceitful above all things

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> time

nothing here has been anywhere

> cant have the same moment of time twice

we may dream of many places, but we are not actually there

> we can think of the future

diving, flying or driving -- moving from wherever, to wherever with whoever, doing whatever

> time flies

nothing here has been anywhere
(except perhaps, round the bend)

> anything outside a (round) clock?

my brother's never told a lie

> time and place?

I'll deceive you any way I can

> times will change i guess

nothing on these steps has ever felt the need to die.

> cant understand this one

altogether but unseen however long your eyes persist

> cant see time

you ll never walk through my locked doors again

> cant go back in time

Comment: It's a good guess, though no, it's not Time! I did put in another hint if you're interested in taking another crack at it!